# Changing font in GUI program

Tags: java, user-interface

I am writing a program for school that uses a GUI interface to change the appearance of text.  This includes making it bold, italicized, and changing the size of it.  I figured out how to italicize and bold the text, but when I tried to figure out how to change the size of the text, it compiles, but when I try to run it I receive the output: Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[].  How do I fix this, and how do I change the size of the text if I did not do this properly?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class StyleGUI
{

    private final int WIDTH = 300, HEIGHT = 150;
    private int fontSize = 36;
    private int style = Font.PLAIN;
    private JLabel saying;
    private JCheckBox bold, italic, small, medium, large;
    private JPanel primary;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Sets up a panel with a label and some check boxes that
    //  control the style of the label's font.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public StyleGUI()
    {
 saying = new JLabel ("Say it with style!");
 saying.setFont (new Font ("Helvetica", style, fontSize));


 bold = new JCheckBox ("Bold");
 bold.setBackground (Color.cyan);
 italic = new JCheckBox ("Italic");
 italic.setBackground (Color.cyan);
 small = new JCheckBox ("Small");
 small.setBackground (Color.cyan);
 medium = new JCheckBox ("Medium");
 medium.setBackground (Color.cyan);
 large = new JCheckBox ("Large");
 large.setBackground (Color.cyan);


 StyleListener listener = new StyleListener();
 bold.addItemListener (listener);
 italic.addItemListener (listener);
 small.addItemListener (listener);
 medium.addItemListener (listener);
 large.addItemListener (listener);


 primary = new JPanel();
 primary.add (saying);
 primary.add (bold);
 primary.add (italic);
 primary.add (small);
 primary.add (medium);
 primary.add (large);

 primary.setBackground (Color.cyan);
 primary.setPreferredSize (new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Returns the primary panel containing the GUI.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public JPanel getPanel()
    {
 return primary;
    }


   //*****************************************************************
   //  Represents the listener for both check boxes.
   //*****************************************************************
   private class StyleListener implements ItemListener
   {
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      //  Updates the style of the label font style.
      //--------------------------------------------------------------
      public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent event)
      {
   style = Font.PLAIN;

   if (bold.isSelected())
       style = Font.BOLD;

   if (italic.isSelected())
       style += Font.ITALIC;

   if (small.isSelected())
     style -= fontSize;

     if (medium.isSelected())
      style = fontSize;

     if (large.isSelected())
        style += fontSize;


     saying.setFont (new Font ("Helvetica", style, fontSize));
      }
   }
}




import javax.swing.*;

public class StyleOptions
{
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates and presents the program frame.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      JFrame styleFrame = new JFrame ("Style Options");
      styleFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      StyleGUI gui = new StyleGUI();
      styleFrame.getContentPane().add (gui.getPanel());

      styleFrame.pack();
      styleFrame.show();
   }
}
```

Comment: Font styles are bit wise operations, that is, BOLD | ITALIC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are receiving is quite clear, probably you are trying to run `StyleGUI`, not `StyleOptions`, which is the class that contains the `main` method and so the entry point of the Java application.

You are doing some errors when assigning the style and font size. Regarding font style, I'd say you are missing to use the `+=` operator on setting the `BOLD`.

About the styles I'd say you should define a default, medium size and add or subtract to it depending on which checkbox is checked. Since i suppose only one of the sizes can be selected at a time, you could consider using a `CheckboxGroup`.

It could be something like this

**StyleGUI**

```
private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 36;

...
int fontSize = DEFAULT_SIZE;

if (small.isSelected())  fontSize = DEFAULT_SIZE - 5;     
if (medium.isSelected()) fontSize = DEFAULT_SIZE;
if (large.isSelected())  fontSize = DEFAULT_SIZE + 5;

...
```

Comment: how do I add a CheckboxGroup?

Comment: RadioButtons would be better.  [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton) you have an example

Comment: Font styles are bit wished operations, that is BOLD | ITALIC,  they should never be added or subtracted

Comment: CheckBoxGroup relates to AWT components, not Swing composts as the OP is using...

Comment: @MadProgrammer It does not matter if you do bitwise operations or directly add or subtract as long as the result is correct. In this case, as style can be any of PLAIN, BOLD, ITALIC or BOLD+ITALIC and according to the values they can take, you can add or substract without problems. [Java Font docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#PLAIN)

Comment: @MadProgrammer True about AWT. I don't know if there's an equivalent in Swing, that's why I recommended using Radio Buttons :)

Comment: I'd beg to differ  the API clear states that the styles are expected to bit wised or'rd, there is an expectation within the API, which could effect the outcome in other areas of the api

Comment: It's not the API concern how do you form the parameters the API receives as long as they conforms to what the API expects. Having said that, i prefer using bitwise operations when setting styles.